# How to simply track flash views with Google Analytics?

Tags: flash, actionscript, google-analytics

Tracking should be independent of hosted page. So flash views should be able to recorded on pages that don't have Google Analytics code.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't drive a car if you haven't got one. How can you expect to have Google Analytics working if you haven't implemented it?

Comment: As far as I know, it can be implemented into flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to the [Google documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingSetupFlash.html) and [download](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/downloads/list) Google analytic library for the Flash. And after you include downloaded swc to your project it's as easy as:

```
import com.google.analytics.AnalyticsTracker; 
import com.google.analytics.GATracker; 
var tracker:AnalyticsTracker = new GATracker( this, "UA-111-222", "AS3", true ); 
playGame.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick ); 
function onButtonClick ( event:Event ):void 
{
   tracker.trackPageview("/somebodyClickedButton"); 
}
```